# Where to find a state of art relation extraction dataset

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a dataset which contains large quantities of relation tuples. For example, the search of "people" and "location" yields "lives in", "worked in", etc. University of Washington's OpenIE http://OpenIE.cs.washington.edu is a good tool but their dataset is only accessible through web. Where can I download a database or library like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. OpenIE itself provides large dataset of 11 gb for this purpose. Check this

http://knowitall.cs.washington.edu/paralex/

Although it is an auto answering system, you can consider intermediate relation extraction result for your purpose.

2. Another method you could implement is using `syntex parse`. Use syntex parser and write rules to extract subject, object and other entities as per your requirement.

Comment: It seems reverb's 3.4g dataset is a good choice. What is the rest 8g data for?

Comment: @Yangrui: yeah. 3.4g itself is 11.4. When you unzip 3.4gb data, it expand to 11.4gb. Well you can vote if the answer if it helped

Comment: I have just attached ReVerb database. It contains lots of relations but still not as good as their website. OpenIE website not only has more tuples but also displays frequency at the result page which is very desired for my project. It is possible to download it's entire database or is there an API?

Comment: @Yangrui entire database is available, could not you download 3.4gb dataset?

Answer (score 5):

I've been collecting all the public datasets containing relationships between named-entities or nominals.

You can find them here:

https://github.com/davidsbatista/Annotated-Semantic-Relationships-Datasets